# ios 9.3.1 doesn't show smart banner on safari on a dev environment

Tags: ios, smartbanner, ios9.3

I'm having an issue trying to test the smart banner on ios 9.3.1. I've tried it on real devices with ios 9.3.1 on a dev env where the smart banner doesn't show but is present on 9.2.1. 
The same meta tag is on production and there the smart banner shows on ios 9.3.1. 
The only difference that I can see is that on the production I have the apple-app-site-association json file and I don't have it on dev. 
But it works fine on ios 9.2...

this is the metatag that I've used

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=XXXXXX, app-argument=appxxxxxxxx://home">
```

Thanks